# Installing libmtp

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch

When I try to run this in terminal, I got this:

```
badar:~$ sudo apt-get install libmtp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmtp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`libmtp` does not exist in the official Ubuntu repositories. What you are looking for is probably `libmtp9`, which you can install using:

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp9
```